# Unable to use frollmean and %>%

Tags: r, magrittr

I want to pipe my data table to frollmean to calculate rolling average of a column. But I am unable to get it work

```
head(mergedDT)
        date Operating_hours DRIVING_TIME net_hrs workday
1 2018-03-20             110          759       0    TRUE
2 2018-03-21             121          641      11    TRUE
3 2018-03-22             133          625      12    TRUE
4 2018-03-23             145          672      12    TRUE
5 2018-03-24             145            0       0   FALSE
6 2018-03-25             145            0       0   FALSE
  n_alarms
1        8
2        5
3        4
4        4
5        1
6        1

mergedDT %>% frollmean("n_alarms",2)
```

Comment: Wich error message do you get?

Comment: Error in froll(fun = "mean", x = x, n = n, fill = fill, algo = algo, align = align,  : 
  x must be list, data.frame or data.table of numeric types

Comment: And which libraries do you load?

Comment: Try mergedDT %>% select(n_alarms) %>% frollmean(2)

Comment: library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

Comment: it works as [[1]]
  [1]   NA  6.5  4.5  4.0  2.5  1.0  4.0  7.5  6.0  4.5  4.0  2.0
but, I need them as an additional column in my data table

Comment: If the question is basically how to add a column to a data frame, that should be covered by many tutorials on getting started in R. [Here's](https://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-add-variables-to-a-data-frame-in-r/) one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
mergedDT %>%  mutate(mean=frollmean(n_alarms,2))
```